# Как создать массив DOM елементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, dom

Мне нужно создать массив класса .tab_p, потом получить каждого из них высоту и назначить всем элементам данного класса наибольшую высоту. Проблема в том, что массив вроде как создается, но высота почему-то считается только первого элемента, а остальные элементы в массиве имеют нулевую высоту. Вот код:

```
var arr_height = $(".tab_p");
        for(var i = 0; i < arr_height.length; i++){
            var frst_height = $(".frst_p").height();
            var new_height = $(arr_height[i]).height();
            if(new_height > frst_height){
                $(".tab_p").height(new_height);
            }
        }
```

Код html

```
<div class="tab_content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab active_tab_content">
                <p class="tab_p">1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                <p class="tab_p">22</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab3" class="tab">
                <p class="tab_p">333</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab4" class="tab">
                <p class="tab_p">4444</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab5" class="tab">
                <p class="tab_p">55555</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

В переменную new_height заносится значение первого элемента (275px), следовательно все элементы класса .tab_p получают 275pх.

Comment: Пожалуйста, учтите Ваши ошибки: не масив, а *массив*, не следыватльно, а *следовательно*, не елементы, а *элементы*.

Comment: @Pavel Osypov А вот эти .tab_p скорее всего располагаются вместе, вряд? И наверняка у них есть элемент-родитель?

Comment: Извините, исправлюсь))

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю угадал или нет, но кажется вам просто надо обернуть все **`.tab_p`** в родителя с **`display:flex`**

```js
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".tab_p").each(function(){
  var itemHeight = $(this).height();
  if (itemHeight > maxHeight)
    maxHeight = itemHeight;
});
$(".tab_p").css("height", maxHeight + "px");
```

```css
#tab_p-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.tab_p {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab_p-wrapper">
  <div class="tab_p">qwe qwe</div>
  <div class="tab_p">qwe qwe qwe qwe qwe</div>
  <div class="tab_p">qwe qwe qwe</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function SetMaxHeight() {
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $(".tab_p").each(function() {
    var itemHeight = $(this).height();
    if (itemHeight > maxHeight)
      maxHeight = itemHeight;
  });
  $(".tab_p").css("height", maxHeight + "px");
}
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="SetMaxHeight()">Click</button>
<div class="tab_content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab active_tab_content">
    <p class="tab_p">1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <p class="tab_p">22</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    <p class="tab_p" style="height:50px;">333</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab">
    <p class="tab_p">4444</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab5" class="tab">
    <p class="tab_p">55555</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: кто минусует рабочий ответ? Проявись.

Comment: К сожалению результат тот же что и у меня. Все блоки получили высоту первого. Я добавил html, раньше нужно было...

Comment: @PavelOsypov Вы, наверное, неаккуратно код к себе скопировали :).